# Unable to deploy Rails app into Google Cloud Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I have a Rails app running locally with Docker and now I'm trying to deploy it to Google Cloud Platform using Cloud Run, following this great [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-run-on-rails-a-real-life-example-part-1-preparing-the-ground-705c94ab8a7a) by Laurent Julliard.

I'm using following GCP services:

- **Cloud Build** to build the container image.
- **Cloud Run** for the deploy.
- **Cloud Storage** for Rails Active Storage.
- **Cloud SQL** for my Postgres DB.
- **Cloud Key Management Service** for my secrets.

*Last 3 services are not relevant for this issue (I think ‍♂️).*

**My deploy process has 2 steps:**

1. Build the container image using Cloud Build
2. Deploy the image using Cloud Run

### Build the container image using Cloud Build

**cloudbuild.yaml** file describe the steps Cloud Build has to go through to build your container.

```
steps:

# Decrypt Rails Master key file
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ["kms", "decrypt", "--ciphertext-file=./config/master.key.enc", 
         "--plaintext-file=./config/master.key",
         "--location=us-central1","--keyring=whale-on-rails", 
        "--key=rails_master_key"]

# Decrypt Whale on Rails service account credentials
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ["kms", "decrypt", "--ciphertext-file=./config/whale_on_rails.key.enc", 
         "--plaintext-file=./config/whale_on_rails.key",
         "--location=us-central1","--keyring=whale-on-rails", 
         "--key=whale_on_rails_key"]

# Build image with tag 'latest' and pass decrypted Rails DB password as argument
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build',
    '--tag', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/whale_on_rails:latest',
    '--build-arg', 'DB_PWD',
    '--build-arg', 'RUBY_VERSION=${_RUBY_VERSION}',
    '--build-arg', 'PG_MAJOR=${_PG_MAJOR}',
    '--build-arg', 'NODE_MAJOR=${_NODE_MAJOR}',
    '--build-arg', 'YARN_VERSION=${_YARN_VERSION}',
    '--build-arg', 'BUNDLER_VERSION=${_BUNDLER_VERSION}',
    '--build-arg', 'RAILS_ENV=${_RAILS_ENV}',
    '--build-arg', 'REDIS_URL=${_REDIS_URL}',
    '--build-arg', 'DATABASE_HOST=${_DATABASE_HOST}',
    '--build-arg', 'DATABASE_USER=${_DATABASE_USER}',
    '--build-arg', 'DATABASE_NAME=${_DATABASE_NAME}',
    '.'
  ]
  secretEnv: ['DB_PWD']
  env:
    - RAILS_ENV=${_RAILS_ENV}
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/
    - DATABASE_HOST=/cloudsql/whale-on-rails:us-central1:whale-on-rails-production
    - DATABASE_USER=postgres
    - DATABASE_NAME=whale-on-rails

# Push new image to Google Cloud Registry       
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/whale_on_rails:latest']

secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/whale-on-rails/locations/us-central1/keyRings/whale-on-rails/cryptoKeys/db_pwd_key
  secretEnv:
    DB_PWD: "CiQArHLfBqlON9MNzM+eKp/Un/HJucmgUftgl5LkYBzvLjsXsaQSOQCBzWJBAh061i7dJrNhEQeWqJHgSkaJpRka9w9nxmbiFzHZ1fpXOm0d7FWAi/8v36EDXmWnxkYXsw=="

substitutions:
  _RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.5'
  _PG_MAJOR: '11'
  _NODE_MAJOR: '12'
  _YARN_VERSION: '1.13.0'
  _BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.0.2'
  _RAILS_ENV: production
  _REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/
  _DATABASE_HOST: /cloudsql/whale-on-rails:us-central1:whale-on-rails-production
  _DATABASE_USER: postgres
  _DATABASE_NAME: whale-on-rails
```

**Dockerfile**: this file is invoked by the ‘Build image’ step in Cloud Build.

```
ARG RUBY_VERSION
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG NODE_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG YARN_VERSION
ARG RAILS_ENV

# Add PostgreSQL to sources list
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Add NodeJS to sources list
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -

# Add Yarn to the sources list
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install dependencies
COPY .docker/dev/Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
    nodejs \
    yarn=$YARN_VERSION-1 \
    $(cat /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
    truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Create a directory for the app code
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/src/app
# RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

# Install production dependencies (Gems installation in
# local vendor directory)
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
ENV BUNDLE_FROZEN=true
# Upgrade RubyGems and install required Bundler version 
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION
RUN bundle install

ENV RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true

COPY . .

# Pre-compile Rails assets (master key needed)
RUN yarn install
RUN RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile

# Set Google App Credentials environment variable with Service Account
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${APP_HOME}/config/whale_on_rails.key

# Database environment variables
ARG DATABASE_NAME
ARG DATABASE_HOST
ARG DATABASE_USER
ARG DB_PWD
ENV DATABASE_PASSWORD=$DB_PWD
ENV DATABASE_NAME=$DATABASE_NAME
ENV DATABASE_HOST=$DATABASE_HOST
ENV DATABASE_USER=$DATABASE_USER

RUN chmod +x ${APP_HOME}/.docker/script/entry
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/.docker/script/entry"]
```

**entrypoint**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /usr/src/app

# Create, migrate and seed the Rails production DB
bundle exec rails db:prepare

# Do some protective cleanup
> log/production.log
rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid

# Run the web service on container startup
bundle exec rails server -e production -b 0.0.0.0 -p $PORT
```

Finally, I'm using the following command to build the container.

`$ gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml`

This process works great. The problem comes in the next step...

### Deploy the image using Cloud Run

```sh
$ gcloud beta run deploy whale-on-rails --image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/whale_on_rails \                                                                                              4m 58s Ruby 2.6.5
  --set-cloudsql-instances whale-on-rails-production \
  --region us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --platform managed
```

In this step, I get this error in terminal:

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

And checking out Cloud Run logs, I get this:

```
2019-10-24 13:03:35.448 CEST<main>: warning: timer_create failed: Success, signals racy
2019-10-24 13:03:37.756 CEST=> Booting Puma
2019-10-24 13:03:37.756 CEST=> Rails 6.0.0 application starting in production
2019-10-24 13:03:37.756 CEST=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
2019-10-24 13:03:40.687 CESTExiting
2019-10-24 13:03:40.687 CEST(erb):21:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `“config' for main:Object (NameError)
2019-10-24 13:03:40.687 CEST from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `eval'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.687 CEST from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `result'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.688 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-6.0.0/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.688 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `class_eval'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.688 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `block in execute_hook'
...
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/src/app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/src/app/bin/spring:15:in `require'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from /usr/src/app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from bin/rails:3:in `load'
2019-10-24 13:03:40.689 CEST from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
2019-10-24 13:03:41.492 CESTContainer called exit(1).
```

My question is, why I'm getting this error? Everything looks fine in the hole process and I've followed the tutorial step by step (the only difference is that they are using MySQL and here I'm using Postgres).

Comment: Did you try to run your container on Cloud Shell with a simple `docker run` command? Is it work?

Comment: Does it run locally or in cloud shell? Looks like you're getting a run-of-the-mill Ruby error

Comment: Add the `PORT` environment variable when you run your container: `-e PORT=8080` (8080 is an example)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I get no image name when I create the build. If I run `docker run -it gcr.io/whale-on-rails/whale_on_rails:latest` in Cloud Shell, I get this error `/usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/parser/options.rb:218:in 'parse_peek': No value provided for option '--port' (Thor::MalformattedArgumentError)`

Comment: Same error as the previous one 

Comment: can you share the database.yml file edited without login info, as the gem in charge of communicating with the database is declared there

Comment: @AdriàCarro have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: the problem comes from copy paste of article's `storage.yml`, using curly quotes instead of normal quotes. Changing quotes on line 12 fixed the problem.